# Gedmo Timestampable vs Timestamp oracle

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine, timestamp

I am developing an application with Symfony2 and oracle database, when mapping entities have datetime columns, when i run the command doctrine:migrations:migrate  are created as timestamp colunms oracle, to fill these columns i use gedmo, but I get the following error:

```
 An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO SSFCOMPGENERICO (fecha_creado, fecha_modificado, id, codigo, nombre, creado_por, modificado_por, obs) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["2014-07-01 23:09:36", null, 2, 3, "kjl", "lkj", "lkjl", "jl"]:

ORA-01843: not a valid month
500 Internal Server Error - DBALException
1 linked Exception:

    OCI8Exception »
```

how can i fix it?, change the date format in gedmo , oracle? 
how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to check which version of oracle gedmo support.

Comment: this link explains what happens to data bases and oracle fields, is apparently DoctrineBundle bug. [link](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2731)   just import the service:

oracle.listener:
        class: Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\OracleSessionInit
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postConnect }


now we can generate dates with gedmo!